# CADES signature with Json data in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, certificate

I have below json data I need to apply CAdES-BES Signature with Automatic JSON Canonicalization. Please find my json data below. Helpful link from https://www.example-code.com/Csharp/itida_egypt_cades_bes_json_canonicalization.asp. I follow the steps but still digital signature is not applying. Its returns normal json data.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/invoiceLines/")]
    public IHttpActionResult getEInvoiceLines()
    {

  
        Chilkat.Crypt2 crypt = new Chilkat.Crypt2();
        crypt.VerboseLogging = true;
        Chilkat.Cert cert = new Chilkat.Cert();
        cert.VerboseLogging = true;

        // Set the smart card PIN, which will be needed for signing.
        cert.SmartCardPin = "1245345";

        // There are many ways to load the certificate.  
        // This example was created for a customer using an ePass2003 USB token.
        // Assuming the USB token is the only source of a hardware-based private key..
        bool success = cert.LoadFromSmartcard(@"E"); //Is this Right way To load certificate ?


        Chilkat.JsonObject cmsOptions = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
        // Setting "DigestData" causes OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.5 (digestData) to be used.
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("DigestData", true);
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("OmitAlgorithmIdNull", true);

        // Indicate that we are passing normal JSON and we want Chilkat do automatically
        // do the ITIDA JSON canonicalization:
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("CanonicalizeITIDA", true);

        crypt.CmsOptions = cmsOptions.Emit();

        // The CadesEnabled property applies to all methods that create CMS/PKCS7 signatures. 
        // To create a CAdES-BES signature, set this property equal to true. 
        crypt.CadesEnabled = true;

        crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha256";

        Chilkat.JsonObject jsonSigningAttrs = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("contentType", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("signingTime", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("messageDigest", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("signingCertificateV2", 1);
        crypt.SigningAttributes = jsonSigningAttrs.Emit();

        // By default, all the certs in the chain of authentication are included in the signature.
        // If desired, we can choose to only include the signing certificate:
        crypt.IncludeCertChain = false;

        EInvoiceModel.Example ds = new EInvoiceModel.Example();
        //Start issuer details 
        ds.issuer = new EInvoiceModel.Issuer();
        ds.issuer.type = "B";
        ds.issuer.id = "113317713";
        ds.issuer.name = "Issuer Company";
        //Start issuer address details
        ds.issuer.address = new EInvoiceModel.Address();
        ds.issuer.address.branchID = "1";
        ds.issuer.address.country = "EG";
        ds.issuer.address.governate = "Cairo";
        ds.issuer.address.regionCity = "Nasr City";
        ds.issuer.address.street = "stree1";
        ds.issuer.address.buildingNumber = "Bldg. 0";
        ds.issuer.address.postalCode = "68030";
        ds.issuer.address.floor = "1";
        ds.issuer.address.room = "123";
        ds.issuer.address.landmark = "7660 Melody Trail";
        ds.issuer.address.additionalInformation = "beside Town Hall";
        //Start Receiver details
        ds.receiver = new EInvoiceModel.Receiver();
        ds.receiver.type = "B";
        ds.receiver.id = "3125617";
        ds.receiver.name = "Receiver company";
        //Start Receiver address datails
        ds.receiver.address = new EInvoiceModel.AddressReceiver();
        ds.receiver.address.country = "EG";
        ds.receiver.address.governate = "Cairo";
        ds.receiver.address.regionCity = "Nasr City";
        ds.receiver.address.street = "stree1";
        ds.receiver.address.buildingNumber = "Bldg. 0";
        ds.receiver.address.postalCode = "68030";
        ds.receiver.address.floor = "1";
        ds.receiver.address.room = "123";
        ds.receiver.address.landmark = "7660 Melody Trail";
        ds.receiver.address.additionalInformation = "beside Town Hall";
        //Document type & version
        ds.documentType = "i";
        ds.documentTypeVersion = "1.0";
        DateTime d = new DateTime();
        ds.dateTimeIssued = d; //Invoice date
        ds.taxpayerActivityCode = "9478"; //needed info
        ds.internalID = "WADIn1234"; //Internal Invoice number
        ds.salesOrderReference = "So1234"; //So number //optional
        ds.salesOrderDescription = "SO1234"; //So additional Info //optional
        ds.proformaInvoiceNumber = "SoPro123"; //optional
                                               //Invoiceline Start
        ds.invoiceLines = new List<EInvoiceModel.InvoiceLine>
         {
              new EInvoiceModel.InvoiceLine
              {
                  description = "Computer1",
                  itemType = "GPC",
                  itemCode = "10001774",
                  unitType = "EA",
                  quantity = 2,
                  internalCode = "IC0",
                  salesTotal = 23.99,
                  total = 2969.89,
                  valueDifference = 7.00,
                  totalTaxableFees = 817.42,
                  netTotal = 880.71,
                  itemsDiscount = 5.00,
                  unitValue = new EInvoiceModel.UnitValue
                  {
                     currencySold = "EUR",
                     amountEGP = 189.40,
                     amountSold = 10.00,
                     currencyExchangeRate = 18.94,
                  },
                 discount = new EInvoiceModel.Discount
                  {
                     rate = 7,
                     amount = 66.29

                  },
                 taxableItems = new List<EInvoiceModel.TaxableItem>
                 {
                     new EInvoiceModel.TaxableItem
                     {
                         taxType = "T1",
                         amount = 272.07,
                         subType =  "T1",
                         rate = 12
                     }

                 }

              }

         }; //Invoice Lines End
            //Items total Discount and Sales/NetAmount
        ds.totalDiscountAmount = 76.29;
        ds.totalSalesAmount = 1609.90;
        ds.netAmount = 1533.61;
        //Tax Total Start
        ds.taxTotals = new List<EInvoiceModel.TaxTotal>
         {
           new EInvoiceModel.TaxTotal
           {
              taxType = "T1",
              amount = 477.54,
            }
          };//Tax Total End
            //Total Sales Amount & discounts
        ds.totalAmount = 5191.50;
        ds.extraDiscountAmount = 5.00;
        ds.totalItemsDiscountAmount = 14.00;

        string strResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\path.json", strResultJson);
        // File.WriteAllText(@"ds.json", strResultJson);

        // string jsonToSign = "{ ... }";
        string jsonToSign = strResultJson;

        // Create the CAdES-BES signature.
        crypt.EncodingMode = "base64";

        // Make sure we sign the utf-8 byte representation of the JSON string
        crypt.Charset = "utf-8";

        string sigBase64 = crypt.SignStringENC(jsonToSign);


        // return Ok(ds);
        return Ok(sigBase64);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static string SerializeObject2(object obj, int indent = 0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (obj != null)
            {
                string indentString = new string(' ', indent);

                if (obj is string || obj.IsNumber())
                {
                    sb.Append($"\"{obj}\"");
                }
                else if (obj.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                {
                    sb.Append($"\"{obj.ToString()}\"");
                }
                else if (obj is Array)
                {
                    var elems = obj as IList;
                    sb.Append($"{indentString}- [{elems.Count}] :\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < elems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(SerializeObject2(elems[i], indent + 4));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Type objType = (obj).GetType();
                    PropertyInfo[] props = objType.GetProperties();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                    {
                        if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                        {
                            object propValue = prop.GetValue(obj);
                            var elems = propValue as IList;

                            if (elems != null)
                            {
                                sb.Append($"\"{prop.Name.ToUpper()}\"");
                                foreach (var item in elems)
                                {
                                    sb.Append($"\"{prop.Name.ToUpper()}\"");
                                    sb.Append(SerializeObject2(item, indent + 4));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.Select(p => p.Assembly).ToList().Contains(prop.PropertyType.Assembly))
                                {
                                    sb.Append($"\"{prop.Name.ToUpper()}\"");
                                    sb.Append(SerializeObject2(propValue, indent + 4));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sb.Append($"\"{prop.Name.ToUpper()}\"\"{propValue}\"");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        else if (objType.GetProperty("Item") != null)
                        {
                            int count = -1;

                            if (objType.GetProperty("Count") != null &&
                                objType.GetProperty("Count").PropertyType == typeof(int))
                            {
                                count = (int)objType.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(obj, null);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {
                                object val = prop.GetValue(obj, new object[] { i });
                                sb.Append(SerializeObject2(val, indent + 4));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: cmsOptions.UpdateBool("CanonicalizeITIDA", false); set auto generate CanonicalizeITIDA to false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MagedNabil , have you been able to solve this issue ?

Comment: yes, I had @WanStreet